# Images replaced but still bringing the old images

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

For speed optimization Google suggested certain images to be compressed from GIF to PNG.

I have placed them in the folder mentioned in the manifest. But after loading the site and upon inspecting the site images its again loading the .gif images.

whats happening? I'm just an amateur in Magento. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Clear magento cache.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that !!

Answer (score 0):

Go to magento admin:

> System -> Cache Management

and Flush Catalog Images Cache.

Answer (score 0):

**It's always good to have n98-magerun.** It's a universal tool to manage your platform through the command line.

For **Linux**, the simplest way is to run a terminal, and go to your Magento destination.

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar 
chmod +x ./n98-magerun.phar
```

To get it on **Windows**, you need to visit:

```
https://files.magerun.net/
```

And download it manually.

Once you have it just run:

```
./n98-magerun.phar cache:flush
```

The other way to do it without command line. Just go to your admin panel.
Next steps are:

```
System->Cache Management->Flush
```

It's simple as that.